# How to find centraliser of any element under a group given by generating set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Question  :**  I want to  nd the centralizer of $(1, 2, 4)(5, 6, 8)$ in the group $G = ⟨(1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8), (1, 3, 8)(4, 5, 7)⟩$ is group.

One possible way is to enumerate all elements of $G$ and then check the condition. Is there any other **better way** to find the centralizer of an element ?

I don't want to use any software or any tool.

Comment: Yes, a better way to do it is to use a computer, even if that is not what you want to do. But this does not involve enumerating all of the elements of $G$, it involves finding a base and strong generating set for $G$, from which the order (which is $24$) can be read off.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $\alpha=(1357)(2468)$, $\beta=(138)(457)$, $\gamma=(124)(568)$. An ad hoc approach that occured to me begins by observing that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respect the partition $$\{1,5\}\cup\{2,6\}\cup\{3,7\}\cup\{4,8\}.$$
For example $\beta(\{1,5\})=\{3,7\}=\alpha(\{1,5\})$, $\beta(\{4,8\})=\{1,5\}$,
$\alpha(\{4,8\})=\{2,6\}$ et cetera. In other words, the group $G=\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$ does not act primitively on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,8\}$. Let $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ be those dublets. This gives us a homomorphism $$f:G\to\operatorname{Sym}(\{P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4\})\simeq S_4.$$
Let's identify $P_i$ with $i$ in the image (to move the action into $S_4$). Then
$$
f(\alpha)=(13)(24),\qquad f(\beta)=(134),
$$
This makes it easy to see that $\operatorname{Im}(f)=A_4$.

We need to be able to say more about the kernel. Obviously $f(\alpha^2)=1$. This made me look at $\alpha^2=(15)(37)(26)(48)\in G$. We now see that $\alpha^2$ commutes with $\beta$. Therefore $\alpha^2$ is in the center $Z(G)$. On the other hand in the image side we have the well known copy of $V_4$ with non-trivial elements $f(\alpha)$ together with its conjugates by powers of $f(\beta)$. We calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_1:=\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}&=(1256)(3874)\\
\alpha_2:=\beta^2\alpha\beta^{-2}&=(1458)(2763)
\end{aligned}
$$
and see that $\alpha_1^2=\alpha_2^2=\alpha^2$ as well as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_1\alpha_2&=(1357)(2468)=\alpha,\\
\alpha_1\alpha\alpha_1^{-1}&=(1753)(2864)=\alpha^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
These relations imply easily that the subgroup $H=\langle \alpha,\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$ of eight elements (an isomorphism is given by $\alpha_1\mapsto i$, $\alpha_2\mapsto j$, $\alpha\mapsto k$).

On the other hand, by design $\beta\in N_G(H)$, so we can conclude that
$H\unlhd G$. It also easily follows that $G/H$ is generated by the coset of $\beta$, so $|G/H|=3$.

This implies that $|G|=24$.

Therefore $\operatorname{ker}(f)=\{1_G,\alpha^2\}$. Because the center of $A_4$ is trivial, we can also conclude that $\operatorname{ker}(f)=Z(G)$.

Using the above bits it should be easy to write $\gamma$ in terms of the generators $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as well as show that the centralizer of $\gamma$ has order six, and is generated by $\gamma$ itself and $\alpha^2$.
Recall that in $A_4$ a 3-cycle generates its own centralizer.

Comment: It might be instructive to see how someone who knows what they are doing would handle this :-)

Comment: I left a number of details for you to check and/or fill in. Depends on how familiar you are e.g. with $Q_8$ at which point will you have satisfied yourself :-)

Comment: The subgroup $H$ is, of course, the Cayley permutation representation of the group $Q_8$. The permutation $\beta$ is then included in the semi-direct product $H\rtimes \langle\delta\rangle$, where $\delta$ acts via the outer automorphism $i\mapsto j\mapsto k\mapsto i$.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a slightly shorter answer than Jyrki's but with details omitted. I compose permutations from left to right.

Again, let $\alpha = (1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)$, $\beta = (1,3,8)(4,5,7)$, $\gamma = (1,2,4)(5,6,8)$. Let $\delta := \beta^{-1}\alpha\beta = (1,2,5,6)(3,8,7,4)$. Then $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1} = (1,4,5,8)(2,7,6,3) = \delta\alpha$.

Since $\alpha^2=\delta^2=(\delta\alpha)^2 = (1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8)$, the subgroup $N = \langle \alpha,\delta \rangle$ of $G$ is normal and is isomorphic to $Q_8$. So $G = \langle N,\beta \rangle$ has order $24$.

It is not clear whether we are meant to assume that $\gamma \in G$, but it is not hard to check this. Since ${\rm Fix}(\beta) = \{2,6\}$, ${\rm Fix}(\gamma) = \{3,7\}$ and $\delta\gamma$ maps $\{2,6\}$ to $\{3,7\}$ we would expect $\langle (\delta\alpha)^{-1} \beta (\delta\alpha) \rangle = \langle \gamma \rangle$, and in fact $(\delta\alpha)^{-1} \beta (\delta\alpha) = \gamma^{-1}$.

Now the centralizer of $\gamma$ in $G$ must permute the set  ${\rm Fix}(\gamma) = \{3,7\}$, and the subgroup of $N$ that fixes this set is $\langle \alpha^2 \rangle$, so $C_G(\gamma) = \langle \alpha^2,\gamma \rangle$ is cyclic of order $6$.